# How to select dinamically a mongo database(multitenant)

Tags: javers

I created a bean with Scope(value=prototype) and works fine for repositories with the @JaversSpringDataAuditable annotation.
All data is saved in the appropiate database.

```
 @Bean
 @Scope(value = "prototype")
 @Lazy(value = true)
 public Javers javers() {

     Authentication auth =  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
     String tenantId = null

     if (auth == null) {
         tenantId = "unauthenticated"
     }else{
         tenantId = auth.getName().toString()
     }

     System.out.println("Selected " + tenantId.toString())

     MongoRepository javersMongoRepository =
             new MongoRepository(mongo().getDatabase(tenantId));

     return JaversBuilder.javers()
             .registerJaversRepository(javersMongoRepository)
             .build();
 }
```

In one specific class I need more fine-grained control over Javers commit. When I call a manual commit, always return me "unauthenticated"

This code always save the data in a database called "unauthenticated"

```
@Autowired
Javers javers
def saveDTO(AuthUtils authUtils, DTO dto){
  javers.commit(authUtils.currentUser.email, dto)
}
```

Any help will be appreciable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you have to pass a concrete MongoDatabase to the JaVers instance, and this can't be changed in runtime. For your (multitenant) case, the MongoRepository API should work in this way:

```
MongoDatabaseProvider dbProvider = new MongoDatabaseProvider() {
    public MongoDatabase provide() {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
        ... your code
    }
}

MongoRepository javersMongoRepository =
             new MongoRepository(dbProvider);
}
```

It's easy to implement this API in JaVers. If you would like to do this, we will accept a PR.